# How to layout large dictionary in the form of a table?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some data that I want to present in a table. column in the table can be a header or a value . Some of these headers in turn, have common headers. In other words, I have a tree of headers that I want to show in the table cells and values at the end of it.

**Problem:** How to lay out in the form of table so that the if I have a large dictionary I can scan through it and make a tabular structure of it having nested headers and values in the last cell.

Example :

```
+ Header 1
|---+ Header 2
|   |---- Header 4--- some_value
|   '---+ Header 5 -- some_value
|       |---- Header 8---sub_headers--some_value
|       '---- Header 9
'---+ Header 3
    |---- Header 6
    '---- Header 7
```

Comment: You can use this maybe, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574070/python-display-a-dict-of-dicts-using-a-ui-tree-for-the-keys-and-any-other-widg

Comment: @pnv  .thank you for the response , I wanted to ask one more thing as i am dealing with some pickle files and what i want is to scan those pickle files make a common dictionary and then from that dictionary make a tabular representation